# find the highest value in multiple xml files and display them

Tags: c#, xml

i have this xml file: (its a draft and got multiple ones like this)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Car>
  <Location name = "somewhere">
   <Type type="itstype">
    <Color>Blue</Color>
    <Owner>Bill</Owner>
    <Price>135</Price>
   </Type>
  </Location>
  <Location name = "somewhere">
   <Type type="itstype">
    <Color>Red</Color>
    <Owner>John</Owner>
    <Price>250</Price>
   </Type>
  </Location>
</Car>
```

and I want using C# to read through all the xml files(which this I can do) and find the highest price for each car in each xml file and display them on the screen. (eg. I have 10 xml files I must print out ten high prices one from each xml file along with the name of the car that has that price) Some xml files have more than two cars. 
I tried using this but it only displays the highest price on the last xml file it reads.

```
public List<Cars> carHighestPrice (string carsname)
{
    var highest = from hv in locations
                  from HV in hv.cars
                  orderby HV.votes 
                  where hv.locationName == carsName
                  select HV;
    return highest.ToList();
}
```

this is the method I am using to display them

```
 public void DisplayHighestPrices()
 {
     string str = "";
     foreach (var highest in locationList.locations)
     {
        str = locationList.carHighestPrice (highest.locationName).Last() + Environment.NewLine;

     }
     lbl1.Text = str;
 }
```

EDIT:

```
public String XMLFileName { get; private set; }

    public configXML(String XMLFileName)
    {
        this.XMLFileName = XMLFileName;
    }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0}", XMLFileName);
    }
```

any ideas on how to fix that please?

Comment: Your sample xml file is full of syntax erros. <Type> tag has no closing tag and <Color> tag closes with </Blue> tag. Please fix it first.

Comment: @Seprum I fixed that. Sorry I copied the wrong file! Also the program reads without problem the xml files but I just need to print the highest price from each xml file ( I have 10 so I must have ten prices)

Comment: I can publish XML to LINQ solution if it's suitable for you.

Comment: if that works and does what I want that would be great please! @Seprum

Answer (score 0):

Here is LINQ to XML solution for your case:

```
public int HighestPrice(string xmlFilePath)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
    var cars = doc.Root.Elements("Location").Select(e => e.Element("Type"));
    return cars.Max(c => int.Parse(c.Element("Price").Value));
}
```

Just use this method for each of your xml files to get desired highest value.

Comment: I used that but it shows me an error that it doesnt find the xml file (one of them) I forgot to mention that I am reading all the xml files at once using threads etc..

Comment: That's not this code problem. If you are expecting further help then please give more information about how are you loading your files.

Comment: I am loading my files using an OpenFileDialog..I have a class that takes the name of the xml files and return it as a string where it needs to

Comment: I added it! please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your local variable is overwritten all the time and has only the last highest price.

```
str = locationList.carHighestPrice (highest.locationName).Last() + Environment.NewLine;
```

Can you try replacing the above line with

```
str = string.Concat(str, locationList.carHighestPrice (highest.locationName).Last(),Environment.NewLine)
```

Comment: But the error is not there, its on the method @Seprum gave me